# Fragments restart everytime I switch between them inside BottomNavigationView implemented using Navigation component

Tags: android, navigation

So I implemented Bottom Navigation using Navigation component and everytime i switch between these fragments, the fragments restart rather than reloading previous state. Navigation component is supposed to handle these kinds of situations on its own right? I am attaching my main activity's oncreate method code below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
    getWindow().setExitTransition(new Fade());

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    iv = binding.logoAppbar;
    toolbar = binding.toolbarMain;
    appBarLayout = binding.appbarMain;
    navViewBottom = binding.navViewBottom;

    NavHostFragment navHostFragment =
            (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main);
    navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.homeFragment, R.id.listingsFragment, R.id.featuredFragment, R.id.categoriesFragment
            , R.id.accountFragment, R.id.howItWorksFragment, R.id.aboutUsFragment, R.id.sellingFeesFragment
            , R.id.primeMembershipFragment)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build();


     NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar,navController,appBarConfiguration);
     NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navViewBottom,navController);

    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_nav_menu_icon);

}
```

This is my Home Fragment code which has a recyclerview inside coordinator layout which is inside SwipeRefreshLayout

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Handle the back button event
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    };

    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
}

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (view == null) {

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        view = binding.getRoot();
        recyclerView = binding.recyclerViewHome;
        shimmerFrameLayout = binding.shimmerLayoutHome;
        appBarLayout = binding.appbarHome;
        collapsingToolbarLayout = binding.collapsingToolbarHome;
        swipeRefreshLayoutHome = binding.swipeRefreshLayoutHome;


        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
        listings = new ArrayList<>();

        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

        recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(20);


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(getString(R.string.BASE_URL))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        farmTenderApi = retrofit.create(API.class);

        HomeRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new HomeRecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), listings);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        getFirstPage(pageNo, 10);

        AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener mListener = new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                swipeRefreshLayoutHome.setEnabled(verticalOffset == 0);
            }
        };

        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(mListener);

        //swipe down to refresh
        swipeRefreshLayoutHome.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
                shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                pageNo = 1;
                listings.clear();
                getFirstPage(1, 10);
            }
        });

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull @NotNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    isScrolling = true;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull @NotNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                currentItems = manager.getChildCount();
                totalItems = manager.getItemCount();
                scrolledOutItems = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (isScrolling && (currentItems + scrolledOutItems >= totalItems)) {
                    pageNo++;
                    isScrolling = false;
                    isLoading = true;
                    performPagination(pageNo, 10);

                }
            }
        });

    }
   return view;
}
```

Comment: I think that's how navigation works . read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56162112/stop-reloading-previous-fragment-by-using-navigation-architecure

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply! So do I have to use ViewModel to store  (let's say I have a recyclerview and i need to get it's scroll position back) data and scroll positions?

Comment: https://medium.com/sprinthub/a-step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-use-nav-graph-scoped-viewmodels-cf82de4545ed This medium article might be of help added to @ADM s answer

Comment: I haven't test it yet but with the version 2.4.0 of navigation now supports this feature. Checkout navigation changelog from 2.4.0-alpha01: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha01

Comment: I tried using the latest version (v2.4.0- alpha04 also v2.4.0-alpha01) too.. no luck :\

Comment: @Narendra_Nath okay i will check it out

Comment: You can also try this https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711

Comment: I am trying to do it with navigation component only. But thanks anyways

Comment: RecyclerView automatically saves and restores it's scroll position; it seems like your problem is not with Navigation, but with your fragment itself. Can you include one of the fragments you're having issues with even when using Navigation 2.4?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I've added my fragment code in the question..Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that changing my dependency versions to v2.4.0-alpha05 have solved recreation issues, thanks to everyone who helped...